# Swift 3/4 dash to camel case (Snake to camelCase)

Tags: swift, swift3

I am trying to perform a simple dash to camel case so:
"this-is-my-id" will become "thisIsMyId" in swift 3 (or 4).

No matter what I do I can't find an elegant enough way to do it..:
The following doesn't work:

```
str.split(separator: "-").enumerated().map { (index, element) in
    return index > 0 ? element.capitalized : element
}.reduce("", +)
```

It cries about all bunch of stuff. I am sure there is a simple enough way... Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A combination of all these answers will lead to the following, shortest way (I think - only 2 interations):

```
let str: String = "this-is-my-id"

let result = str.split(separator: "-").reduce("") {(acc, name) in
    "\(acc)\(acc.count > 0 ? String(name.capitalized) : String(name))"
}
```

Thanks all!

Comment: You might want to check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48850292/what-is-the-difference-between-combining-array-by-using-reduce-or-joined) about why to use `joined` instead of `reduce`

Answer (score 9):

Your code is almost correct. The following is the most readable implementation I have found:

```
let str: String = "this-is-my-id"

let result = str
    .split(separator: "-")  // split to components
    .map { String($0) }   // convert subsequences to String
    .enumerated()  // get indices
    .map { $0.offset > 0 ? $0.element.capitalized : $0.element.lowercased() } // added lowercasing
    .joined() // join to one string

print(result)
```

Comment: @Cristik Well, I could probably do the same using `.lazy` after `.split`.

Comment: @Cristik You have to do that anyway. We would have to measure performance to actually get any meaningful answer. However, I think that's over-optimization.

Answer (score 9):

Just a better implementation of @sulthan's answer with Swift 4.1.

```
extension String {
    func camelCased(with separator: Character) -> String {
        return self.lowercased()
            .split(separator: separator)
            .enumerated()
            .map { $0.offset > 0 ? $0.element.capitalized : $0.element.lowercased() }
            .joined()
    }
}
```

Comment: The second `lowercased()` (in `$0.element.lowercased()`) is technically unnecessary, since you've already `lowercased()` the whole string in the first step, but if you don't call it a second time, you have to use `String($0.element)` instead. The beauty of the second `lowercased()` is that it balances the `capitalized` before it.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is to spilt your string based on the dash "-" (creating an array of strings) and combine its elements with the desired case:

```
let myString = "this-is-my-id"
let newString = myString.split(separator: "-").reduce("", { $0 + $1.capitalized })

print(newString) // "ThisIsMyId"
```

Comment: The first letter should be probably lowercase. Also, prefer `joined()` over `reduce("", +)`.

Comment: @Sulthan regardless of "The first letter should be probably lowercase", could you please mention why `joined` is preferable?

Comment: Becase it works with the knowledge of all the elements (array of strings) therefore it can have much better performance. Of course, there is also a boost in code readability.

Comment: @Sulthan if I got it right, is it related to `FlattenBidirectionalCollection` does not create new storage (always lazy)?

Comment: No, it's only about the internal logic. `joined` operates on the final array, therefore it knows the necessary size. `reduce` operates at one element at a time. There is no reason to use a generic function if there is a specific function with possible better performance.

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the desired request. (thisIsMyId vs ThisIsMyId).

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax works if you destructure the `String.Subsequence` elements by creating new strings:

```
str.split(separator: "-").enumerated().map { (index, element) in
     return index > 0 ? String(element).capitalized : String(element)
}.joined() // better than `reduce`
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the smallest implementation of conversioning from dash to camel case using `reduce`:

```swift
extension String {
    var camelCased: String {
        self.split(separator: "-")
            .reduce("", { $0 + ($0.isEmpty ? String($1) : $1.capitalized) })
    }
}

print("this-is-my-id".camelCased) // Prints "thisIsMyId"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the characters (`String` is a collection of characters) while holding a flag telling if the character came after a dash, in order to capitalize it:

```
let dashCase = "this-is-my-id"
let camelCase = dashCase.reduce(into: ("", false)) {
    // mark the dash
    guard $1 != "-" else { $0.1 = true; return }
    $0.0 += $0.1 ? String($1).uppercased() : String($1)
    // reset the flag so we don't capitalize the next ones
    $0.1 = false
}.0
print(camelCase)  // thisIsMyId
```

Comment: Thanks, looks promising, but didn't compile on playground...
Found the shortest way... https://stackoverflow.com/a/48851465/805138