# What is the difference between combining array by using reduce or joined?

Tags: arrays, swift, performance, reduce

Consider the following array -of strings-:

```
let arrayStrings = ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
```

For combining its elements (to get "Hello" as single String), we could:

*[reduce](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce)* it:

```
let reducedString = arrayStrings.reduce("", { $0 + $1 }) // "Hello"
```

Or *[join](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/1641243-joined)* it:

```
let joinedString = arrayStrings.joined() // "Hello"
```

Both would return "Hello" String as output.

However, what is the logic to keep in mind to determine what is the better choice for such a process? What is the difference when comparing based on the performance?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two reasons why `joined` is a better choice than `reduce`:

1. Readability

   If you want to join multiple strings into one string, why would you use `reduce`, with manual concatenation? If there is a specific function for the task you want to do, use it. When reading the code, it's easier to understand `joined` than `reduce`.
2. Performance

   `joined` for `String` can be implemented better than `reduce`. It does not have to be but it can. `reduce` operates on one element at a time, without knowledge about the other elements, with many temporary variables passed around. `joined` has the knowledge of the entire sequence and it knows that the operation is always the same, therefore it can optimize. It can even use the internal structure of `String`. See [String.joined implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/2785bee6e07a7a3a08668c95e4039c5753eb089d/stdlib/public/core/String.swift#L1073).

In summary, always use the more specific implementation.
Note that the performance reason above is the less important one.

Comment: Thanks. So `reduce` would iterate through the sequence and do the process for each element -with all necessary things-, and `joined` treats the whole sequence as one chunk to be combined, is it correct or am I misunderstanding it? I would really appreciate your kind consideration.

Comment: @AhmadF `reduce` iterates through the array, concatenating the next string to the previous result.  I am pretty sure you understand that :) If you look into the implementation of `String.joined` I have linked above, you will see that Swift first goes through the elements to calculate the memory necessary for the result, then it allocates (reserves) the memory and then appends all the strings into it. That means only one memory allocation is needed. `reduce` has to allocate more memory in every step and deallocate all the memory from the previous step. `joined` can also use the internal data.

Comment: @AhmadF The important thing to note is that all that is implementation detail.  Trust the compiler and the API designers and always use the more specific version of a function.

Answer (score 2):

**Update** The previous results were obtained by running an iOS app on the simulator. Running the app on a real device, or running the code from a MacOS command line app gives similar results to ones @Sulthan mentioned.

---

Interestingly enough, `reduce` gave better results on my machine:

```
func benchmark(_ label: String, times: Int = 100000, _ f: () -> Void) {
    let start = CACurrentMediaTime()
    (0..<times).forEach { _ in f() }
    let end = CACurrentMediaTime()
    print("\(label) took \(end-start)")
}

let arrayStrings = ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o"]
benchmark("reduce", { _ = arrayStrings.reduce("", +) } )
benchmark("join", { _ = arrayStrings.joined() })
```

The results were around the following numbers when run from the `main` method of a typical iOS app, build in Debug mode:

```
reduce took 0.358474982960615
join took 0.582276367989834
```

Same app, built in Release mode, gave the same order of results:

```
reduce took 0.126910287013743
join took 0.0291724550188519
```

I ran the benchmarks multiple times, and `reduce` performed better in all cases. The difference is not that big though, so unless your string operations are critical in regards to performance, I'd recommend using `joined`, that method carries more semantical value, it better transmits the intent.

Comment: Did you try it with full optimization and not in a playground?

Comment: @Sulthan so would it be different if we tried it on a real app with release mode?

Comment: My results are consistently 4x faster for `joined` in a simple console app. Playgrounds are not good for performance testing and you cannot check performance in debug mode (with compiler optimizations disabled). Of course, we should also test with longer arrays and longer strings but that's another issue.

Comment: Please note that running this code on *playground* multiple times gave different results.

Comment: @Sulthan I run the code as part of a unit testing bundle, debug mode. Not sure if running the code in an optimized binary would yield different results, though, since the methods we call are part of the same Swift binary.

Comment: @Sulthan I run the benchmarks as part of an app code, in both Debug and Release, and as I suspected the results were similar.

Comment: In you "Release mode" results `join` is 4x times better than `reduce`.

Comment: @Sulthan my bad, I was running the code into the context on an iOS app, on the simulator. Running the app on a real device, or a command line tool gives results similar to yours.