# Codable decoding values in JSON converting snake case to camel

Tags: json, swift, codable

When using Swift `Codable` you can specify a `keyDecodingStrategy` that will convert snake_case to camelCase. This works great for keys in a dictionary, but is there any solution for decoding values in a dictionary in a similarly clean way?

I have an enumeration that is used as a key in one place and as a value in another:

```
enum Foo: String, Codable, CodingKey, CaseIterable {
   case bar
   case bazQux // baz_qux in JSON, say
}
```

Then this is used as a key like so:

```
struct MyStruct: Codable {
    enum Keys: String, CodingKey {
        case myKey
    }

    let myProperty: [Bool]

    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: Foo.self)

        myProperty = Foo.allCases.map {
            try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: $0)
        }
    }
}
```

But it is also used as a value like so:

```
struct Buz: Decodable {
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case foo
    }

    // Note this is called using a decoder with keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let foo = try container.decode(Foo.self, forKey: .foo)
    }
}
```

The JSON for example might include a line like this:

```
"foo": "baz_qux"
```

The value decoding only works if I set the raw value of the `bazQux` case to be `baz_qux`. But then that breaks the key decoding. It would also be annoying to have to make two separate enums for the same thing just to avoid this problem.

So I can then initialize the right model corresponding to the value.

I'd also like to avoid employing a "hacky" solution… Is there something reasonably elegant that works well with `Codable`?

Comment: What is the purpose of `allCases.map`? The decoded values are unused.

Comment: This is just a snippet. Edited it a bit, does that make it more clear?

Comment: I don't think there is any out-of-the-box solution for decoding values without using a custom init, I would suggest looking at the answers in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48849452/swift-3-4-dash-to-camel-case-snake-to-camelcase) for converting to camel case

Comment: To clarify, you want to decode `{ "foo": "baz_qux" }` into a `struct A { var foo: Foo }`, and `{"baz_qux": true}` into an array of Bool values based on keys? So, why not use the default decoding strategy instead of converting snake_case to camelCase? It doesn't look like you use these keys anywhere except to extract their boolean value

Comment: the code samples are just simplified for the sake of the question

Comment: @shim, makes sense, but sometimes one could simplify a bit too much... I think that's why people are not sure what to recommend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wound up adding a custom decoding initializer on `Foo`:

```
 public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let rawValue = try decoder.singleValueContainer().decode(String.self)
    if let foo = Self.init(rawValue: rawValue.snakeToCamelCase) {
      self = foo
    } else {
      throw CodingError.unknownValue
    }
  }
```

`snakeToCamelCase` is a simple extension method on `String` I added locally. Plus need to add the `enum CodingError: Error` to `Foo` if you want some error handling.

This isn't ideal but at least it's not too complicated. I would rather rely on built-in case conversion methods but I don't see a way to do that here.